# Visual Studio 2012 Debugging Issues

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

Im trying to Debug my project but when i try, i get the following error

```
 "Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program C:\Users\ME\Documents\VisualStudio2012\Projects\Application1\Application1\bin\Debug\Application1.exe" 
 The network connection to the Visual Studio Remote Debugger has been closed.
```

Im not debugging remotely, and when i go to the path specified above, the project comes up when i double click it, what is going on here?

```
 Operating System is 64-Bit Windows 7 Professional
```

Visual Studio Starts in path below

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: Pretty standard.  Your attempt at debugging looks like a viral attack to the crapware installed on your machines.  Turn it off.

Comment: This is a work computer, nothing really installed on it